# Object gets empty in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I suppose that is very basic question, but I don't really understand, why do I get different results. Inside `function(data)` the map fills and show as filled. When I get out, it flushes.What is wrong? Strangely, first thing that I receive in my Chrome JS Console is `console.log(map)` from inner function, not the last one, so they seem to be printed out in reverse order.

```
var map = {};

var deps = $.get("#####", function (data) {

    $.each(data, function (tag, data) {
        $.each(data, function (param, info) {
            if (param == 'name')
                map[tag] = param;
        });
    });
    console.log(map)
});

console.log(map)
```

Comment: Have you checked data?

Comment: what does your data object look like?

Answer (score 5):

The last line, `console.log(map)` executes before the callback function. When it executes, the request hasn't finished yet, so `map` is still empty.